# Issue with Elastic search 6.x in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

> report.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento233_ela6_product_1_v6","node":"C3kR1cBBR0y_TcZ3EZQgmQ","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}}},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento233_ela6_product_1_v6\",\"node\":\"C3kR1cBBR0y_TcZ3EZQgmQ\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.\"}}],\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [category_ids] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.\"}}},\"status\":400}

Facing this issue when we have Magento 2.3.3 and ES 6.x and PHP7.2

Magento given doc https://magento1544124303.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031328652-illegal-argument-exception-on-category-page-with-Elasticsearch-5-0-Fielddata-is-disabled-on-text-fields-by-default-
not even help here.

Anybody having idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use latest ES version - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/release-notes-6.8.6.html .. It will solve the issue if you don't have 3rd party modules otherwise 3rd party modules also requires upgrade.

Comment: But Magento 2.3 support 6.5.x only right? Will it support 6.8?

Comment: We have tried that too. Still same issue.

Comment: is category_ids a custom attribute created by you or a module?

Comment: I had something like this when i upgraded.  There was an error in my code and the Indexing within Magento wasn't completing.  More info would be helpful.  Have you written your own module?  Did it work before on a previous Magento/Elastic version?

Comment: category_ids is magento's system attribute.

Comment: yes, it worked in 2.2.8 edition without any issue

Comment: elasticsearch cannot process the data in that attribute, although it is a system attribute. I am using 2.3.3 with elasticsearch 6.x too without any problems. have you tried completely rebuilding the es data?

Comment: unfortunately we are getting error with the category_ids attribute. How can I assure whether this attribute pushed to ES?

Answer (score 9):

Got across this several times and we came across this https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027356612-Elasticsearch-5-is-configured-but-search-page-does-not-load-with-Fielddata-is-disabled-error which not only identifies the problem but also gives a fix which works with several Magento versions. I tried 2.3.5 and 2.4.2.

By default, **only certain types of product attributes can be used in Layered Navigation**. **They are Yes/No, Dropdown, Multipleselect, and Price**. That is why in Magento Admin, you cannot set an attribute of any other type as Use in Layered Navigation = Filterable or Use in Search Results Layered Navigation = Yes. But there is a technical possibility to get around this limitation by directly changing the is_filterable and is_filterable_in_search values in the database. If this happens, and any other attribute type, like Date, Text, etc., is set to be used in Layered Navigation, Elasticsearch 5 (my edit: and others like ElasticSearch 6 and 7) throws an exception.

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on
> [%attribute_code%]] in order to load fielddata in memory by
> uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use
> significant memory.

Step 1. Identify the product attributes which generate the issue using an SQL tool like phpmyadmin

```
SELECT ea.attribute_code, ea.frontend_input, cea.is_filterable, cea.is_filterable_in_search FROM eav_attribute AS ea
    INNER JOIN catalog_eav_attribute AS cea ON ea.attribute_id = cea.`attribute_id`
    WHERE (is_filterable = 1 OR is_filterable_in_search = 1) AND frontend_input NOT IN ('boolean', 'multiselect', 'select', 'price');
```

To fix the issue, you need to set is_filterable (that is, used in Layered Navigation) and filterable_in_search (that is, used in search results Layered Navigation) to "0" (not used).

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute AS cea
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
        ON ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
SET cea.is_filterable = 0, cea.is_filterable_in_search = 0
WHERE (cea.is_filterable = 1 OR cea.is_filterable_in_search = 1) 
    AND frontend_input NOT IN ('boolean', 'multiselect', 'select', 'price');
```

then reindex all

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

The fix says to reindex only `catalogsearch_fulltext` but this won't work if you have custom search modules since they use different indexes.

Comment: legend! great work

Comment: This saved me a Ton of time ... Thanks a ton @Mike !!!

Comment: Getting same issue but the attribute type is drop down. Could you plz suggest this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359064/text-fields-are-not-optimised-error-in-system-log-but-its-not-a-text-field