# Magento 2 some products not showing in categories/search

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, catalogsearch, category-products

Some of my configurable products do not show inthe front end when trying to navigate to them through categories or when I search for them.

They do appear in the backend.

They do appear in the frontend when accesing their direct link.

They also appear in the home page.

This seems to be happening only with configurable products that have more than about 650 records.If I delete aconfigurable product and create it again with less combinations, it does appear everywhere.

The products are Enabled.
Visibility is Catalog, Search.
Products are In Stock.
Is Featured? marked as Yes.
The products are in the propper category and they appear under the category tree in the backend.
Quantity is 10 on all products.
Products are in Main Website.

I've ran indexer:reindex and flushed the cache many times as well.

EDIT:

I also tried the following commands:

sudo service elasticsearch start
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento c:f

It didn't work either.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/309645/34579  - Try to implement the given solution and see whether configurable product ids are returning or not from ElasticSearch.